# Start a timer shared between 2 or more apps

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

At the moment I am working on a gps-oriented game. All the players playing have 2 hours to complete it. They are all using the same app on a different device.

So the question is; Is it possible to start a timer from a device that is being shared between all the other devices, and also being showed on all of them? 
If that's not possible, maybe someone knows another tactic to start a timer that after it's being started all exactly have the same amount of time left.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Without knowing more about your architecture--Every device will have its own time system. You will need an independent and singular time reference. You could supply that time reference from your own server or a internet time service. Again--not knowing who initiates the game, how the players access the game or what resources you have at your disposal it makes it difficult to give a qualified answer.

Comment: Let's say there are 2 teams playing the game. 1 team of people trying to escape, and 1 team trying to find them. I want the team trying to escape to start the game when they are ready to "flee" from the other team by pressing on a button "Start game". After they press that button the game starts and the timer will be run and shown on both devices.

Comment: I agree w/ @Barns, the key word in your question is **shared**, thus you need a centralized source, whether that is your own app server or via a 3rd party source. Google and Apple both have "game" server/service platforms (platform dependent) that can provide a central/coordinated time among players and the platform-independent services like Google's Firebase have a server-based timestamp that you can add to a record and thus be shared to all clients that join the "game" via its real-time subscriptions.